# Не устанавливается Scrapy

Tags: macos, terminal, scrapy

Пытаюсь установить Scrapy с помощью скачанного [отсюда](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy) архива:
Терминал отдает:

```
Last login: Sat May  5 22:27:02 on ttys000
PCName-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ python /Volumes/F/sandbox/scrapy-master/setup.py open
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Volumes/F/sandbox/scrapy-master/setup.py", line 34, in <module>
long_description=open('README.rst').read(),
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'README.rst'
PCName-MacBook-Pro:~ username$
```

Скрин содержимого папки: [image: содержимое архива scrapy]

README.rst лежит в той же директории! **Как указать terminal, что файл рядом?**

Comment: Лучше использовать команду `pip install scapy`.

Answer (score 0):

Открыть файл **setup.py** на строчке 34 добавить **./**

```
./README.rst
```

Answer (score 0):

В общем, пришел настоящий программист – руководитель проекта и все пофиксил:

```
sudo python3 get-pip.py
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/username/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Collecting pip
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0f/74/ecd13431bcc456ed390b44c8a6e917c1820365cbebcb6a8974d1cd045ab4/pip-10.0.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 6.4MB/s 
Collecting wheel
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1b/d2/22cde5ea9af055f81814f9f2545f5ed8a053eb749c08d186b369959189a8/wheel-0.31.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (41kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 51kB 14.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip, wheel
  Found existing installation: pip 9.0.3
    Uninstalling pip-9.0.3:
      Successfully uninstalled pip-9.0.3
Successfully installed pip-10.0.1 wheel-0.31.0
```

А потом и Scrapy следом встал:

```
PCName-MacBook-Pro:~ username$ python3 -m pip install Scrapy
Collecting Scrapy
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/9c/cb15b2dc6003a805afd21b9b396e0e965800765b51da72fe17cf340b9be2/Scrapy-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (251kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 2.8MB/s 
Collecting Twisted>=13.1.0 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/12/2a/e9e4fb2e6b2f7a75577e0614926819a472934b0b85f205ba5d5d2add54d0/Twisted-18.4.0.tar.bz2 (3.0MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 3.0MB 3.1MB/s 
Collecting w3lib>=1.17.0 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/37/94/40c93ad0cadac0f8cb729e1668823c71532fd4a7361b141aec535acb68e3/w3lib-1.19.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting parsel>=1.1 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/bc/b4/2fd37d6f6a7e35cbc4c2613a789221ef1109708d5d4fb9fd5f6f721a43c9/parsel-1.4.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting service-identity (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/29/fa/995e364220979e577e7ca232440961db0bf996b6edaf586a7d1bd14d81f1/service_identity-17.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cssselect>=0.9 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/7b/44/25b7283e50585f0b4156960691d951b05d061abf4a714078393e51929b30/cssselect-1.0.3-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting PyDispatcher>=2.0.5 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/cd/37/39aca520918ce1935bea9c356bcbb7ed7e52ad4e31bff9b943dfc8e7115b/PyDispatcher-2.0.5.tar.gz
Collecting pyOpenSSL (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/79/db/7c0cfe4aa8341a5fab4638952520d8db6ab85ff84505e12c00ea311c3516/pyOpenSSL-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (53kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 9.2MB/s 
Collecting six>=1.5.2 (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/67/4b/141a581104b1f6397bfa78ac9d43d8ad29a7ca43ea90a2d863fe3056e86a/six-1.11.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting queuelib (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/4c/85/ae64e9145f39dd6d14f8af3fa809a270ef3729f3b90b3c0cf5aa242ab0d4/queuelib-1.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting lxml (from Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a4/7c/0c333ccdaa04628b4df46d36b8a700d7810ffecd1371de796e2403fe9380/lxml-4.2.1-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.macosx_10_9_intel.macosx_10_9_x86_64.macosx_10_10_intel.macosx_10_10_x86_64.whl (8.7MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 8.7MB 1.9MB/s 
Collecting zope.interface>=4.4.2 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ac/8a/657532df378c2cd2a1fe6b12be3b4097521570769d4852ec02c24bd3594e/zope.interface-4.5.0.tar.gz (151kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 153kB 6.6MB/s 
Collecting constantly>=15.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/b9/65/48c1909d0c0aeae6c10213340ce682db01b48ea900a7d9fce7a7910ff318/constantly-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting incremental>=16.10.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f5/1d/c98a587dc06e107115cf4a58b49de20b19222c83d75335a192052af4c4b7/incremental-17.5.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting Automat>=0.3.0 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/17/6a/1baf488c2015ecafda48c03ca984cf0c48c254622668eb1732dbe2eae118/Automat-0.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting hyperlink>=17.1.1 (from Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a7/b6/84d0c863ff81e8e7de87cff3bd8fd8f1054c227ce09af1b679a8b17a9274/hyperlink-18.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pyasn1-modules (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e9/51/bcd96bf6231d4b2cc5e023c511bee86637ba375c44a6f9d1b4b7ad1ce4b9/pyasn1_modules-0.2.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (60kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 7.5MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1 in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from service-identity->Scrapy) (0.3.7)
Collecting attrs (from service-identity->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/41/59/cedf87e91ed541be7957c501a92102f9cc6363c623a7666d69d51c78ac5b/attrs-18.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting cryptography>=2.1.4 (from pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/40/87/acdcf84ce6d25a7db1c113f4b9b614fd8d707b7ab56fbf17cf18cd26a627/cryptography-2.2.2-cp34-abi3-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (1.5MB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.5MB 3.5MB/s 
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from zope.interface>=4.4.2->Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy) (39.0.1)
Collecting idna>=2.5 (from hyperlink>=17.1.1->Twisted>=13.1.0->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/27/cc/6dd9a3869f15c2edfab863b992838277279ce92663d334df9ecf5106f5c6/idna-2.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl (56kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 61kB 9.6MB/s 
Collecting cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy" (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8e/be/40b1bc2c3221acdefeb9dab6773d43cda7543ed0d8c8df8768f05af2d01e/cffi-1.11.5-cp36-cp36m-macosx_10_6_intel.whl (241kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 245kB 4.7MB/s 
Collecting asn1crypto>=0.21.0 (from cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ea/cd/35485615f45f30a510576f1a56d1e0a7ad7bd8ab5ed7cdc600ef7cd06222/asn1crypto-0.24.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (101kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 102kB 6.7MB/s 
Collecting pycparser (from cffi>=1.7; platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"->cryptography>=2.1.4->pyOpenSSL->Scrapy)
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/2d/aad7f16146f4197a11f8e91fb81df177adcc2073d36a17b1491fd09df6ed/pycparser-2.18.tar.gz (245kB)
    100% |████████████████████████████████| 256kB 4.3MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: Twisted, PyDispatcher, zope.interface, pycparser
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for Twisted ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/b3/76/f7/85353c829c0881e74b5366ce0ed59042b098bb4903e2da8828
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for PyDispatcher ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/88/99/96/cfef6665f9cb1522ee6757ae5955feedf2fe25f1737f91fa7f
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for zope.interface ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/c6/b2/d2/be6785a207eaa58d76debc10c9d5c66196b40a88abb61d6af7
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for pycparser ... done
  Stored in directory: /Users/username/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/c0/a1/27/5ba234bd77ea5a290cbf6d675259ec52293193467a12ef1f46
Successfully built Twisted PyDispatcher zope.interface pycparser
pyasn1-modules 0.2.1 has requirement pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.1, but you'll have pyasn1 0.3.7 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: zope.interface, constantly, incremental, six, attrs, Automat, idna, hyperlink, Twisted, w3lib, cssselect, lxml, parsel, pyasn1-modules, pycparser, cffi, asn1crypto, cryptography, pyOpenSSL, service-identity, PyDispatcher, queuelib, Scrapy
Successfully installed Automat-0.6.0 PyDispatcher-2.0.5 Scrapy-1.5.0 Twisted-18.4.0 asn1crypto-0.24.0 attrs-18.1.0 cffi-1.11.5 constantly-15.1.0 cryptography-2.2.2 cssselect-1.0.3 hyperlink-18.0.0 idna-2.6 incremental-17.5.0 lxml-4.2.1 parsel-1.4.0 pyOpenSSL-17.5.0 pyasn1-modules-0.2.1 pycparser-2.18 queuelib-1.5.0 service-identity-17.0.0 six-1.11.0 w3lib-1.19.0 zope.interface-4.5.0
```